# How to run meanstack in docker

Tags: docker, mean-stack, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-image

I am using Mean stack website it is run in node server. I want to run my website in docker.

How to create mean stack Docker image.

I am using windows 8.1 x64

I searched lot but there is no use can any one give me correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is first read the Docker docs about how Docker works: https://docs.docker.com/.

After that you can search for MEAN stack docker repo's on github which you can reuse: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mean+docker&type=.

After that choose the one that fits your needs and change it to your needs. When you get errors report back! Good luck!

Comment: Hi frenus: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mean+docker&type=. i dont know here what to do. i am new to docker. can tell me clearly

Comment: First look into these repo's. Let's say you want to use MEAN stack with Angular 2, I found this one for example: https://github.com/gangachris/mean-docker. Follow the instructions in the repo: e.g. clone it and run docker-compose up. Now you have your MEAN stack containers running. In your browser go to localhost:4200. Then you need to put your code in the right map so it is available in the container and it should be working.

Comment: Hi frenus: i am going to download the proj in "github.com/gangachris/mean-docker."after that i am opened docker quick start terminal. after that i moved to that folder path and follow the instrution in repo. now i am goint go start localhost:4200 . here not open anything. am i doing correct way

Comment: Did you do `docker-compose up`, this will take maybe 2 minutes. After that in your browser type localhost:4200

Comment: ya . after enter that line some line are running in the docker quick start terminal. but nothing will open.

Comment: If you open your browser and go to localhost:4200 nothing shows?

Comment: Does it give any errors in your terminal after running docker-compose up?

Comment: some words going over 2 mints after that, the running words are stoped. then i am going to run on browser. then only i got error like this